# It is possible for sqlalchemy to add field level rule that two specific columns cannot be both None?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Foo(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # omitted lengthy codes...

    spam = db.relationship('Spam')
    spam_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('spams.id'))

    bar = db.relationship('Bar')
    bar_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('bars.id'))

    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())
```

Is there any options available for Flask-SQLAlchemy to add a behaviour that the `spam_id` and `bar_id` cannot be both `None` during insert/update? But will accept if atleast one of these columns has a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [table constraint here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.CheckConstraint)

```
from sqlalchemy import CheckConstraint


class Foo(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # omitted lengthy codes...

    spam = db.relationship('Spam')
    spam_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('spams.id'))

    bar = db.relationship('Bar')
    bar_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('bars.id'))

    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())

    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint('NOT(spam_id IS NULL AND bar_id IS NULL)', name='both_null'),
    )
```

Trying to add a new Foo instance with spam_id with None ? Ok you can

```
foo=Foo(spam_id=None, bar_id=1)
sqlalchemy_session.add(foo)
sqlalchemy_session.commit()
```

Trying to add Foo with both spam_id and bar_id at None ? Nope Sir !

```
foo=Foo(spam_id=None, bar_id=None)
sqlalchemy_session.add(foo)
sqlalchemy_session.commit()  # Raises Exception
```

The raised exception comes from your DBMS, for exemple with PostgresQL and psycopg2 driver it is psycopg2.IntegrityError

Comment: Exactly what i need.